# php regular expression backslash dash

Tags: php, regex

I'm new in PHP and I'm trying to accommodate php regular expression

from w3schools this regular expression

```
"/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/"
```

represents the e-mail regular expression, but I'm wondering what this class definition means `"[\w\-]"`, `\w` any word character **but what about `"\-"`?**

(Edited)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: The regex you have merely represents a "valid" e-mail address. For example, it fails for `foo+bar@baz.qux`. The character class `[\w\-]` will match a word character and a hyphen `-` literally. That said, you don't need to escape a hyphen at the end of a character class, so `[\w-]` is perfectly valid. Also escaping `@` is useless. On a general note, you should avoid w3schools as a source for learning, it has a bad history of outdated, sometimes misleading information. Get a book instead.

Comment: can you provide me a good book to learn PHP briefly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[\w\-]` means letters(capital and small letter both) and numbers including -(dash/hypen)

You may check your regex explanation [here](http://regex101.com/r/tE4jW4/2)

> **`[\w\-]+`** match a single character present in the list below
>
> **Quantifier:** Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>
> **\w** match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
>
> **`\-`** matches the character - literally

Comment: you might forget underscore

Comment: OP is talking about `[\w\\-]`

Comment: @R.T. Please do not just copy and paste from an automated script. [Here's something you might want to read](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate)

Comment: @HamZa:- I do understand that but first I have explained that and then I have added  the link and I dont think that this is a wrong explanation and I deserve the downvote(Downvotes are awarded for wrong or incorrect answers). Anyways its your call and I dont want to discuss it further. Thanks!

Comment: @R.T. That said, the OP is using `[\w\-]` while you're explaining `[\w\\-]` which are slighty different regexes. The OP might get confused :)

Comment: @HamZa:- Yes I saw that. OP firstly used `[\w\\-]` then I think he has changed that!

Comment: @R.T. Ok, I see the "problem". The OP has used a double backslash because of SO's markdown, it showed one backslash correctly. But then @Braj went and added the backticks to "codify" the regex. So markdown will display the double backslash literally. From a logical point of view, it should be `[\w\-]` but you never know with those [fools](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: @HamZa:- Yes I agree. I have updated my answer. Just to make my answer correct. One more edit to question will ask me to delete my answer. As I am really sick of modifying the answer and getting unnecessary downvotes because of irregular edits

Answer (score 7):

### But what about `\-` ?

The hyphen is mostly a normal character in regular expressions.

- Outside of a character class; it has **no** special meaning (*do not need to escape the hyphen*).
- Inside of a character class it **has** special meaning.

You can place a hyphen as the first or last character of the class without escaping.

- ( `[-\w]`, `[\w-]` )

In some regular expression implementations, you can also place directly after a range without escaping.

- ( `[y-z-abc]`, `[\w-abc]` [short-hand class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) )

Simply escaping the hyphen as the last character of the class is fine here.

```
[\w\-]  # any character of: word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), 
        # match a literal hyphen `\-'
```

Answer (score 1):

All `[\w\-]` Means is match and word character `\w` and match any - `\-`

it means the exact same thing as `[\w-]`

Answer (score 0):

`\w` matches any **word** character plus `_`, underscore, i.e. upper and lowercase alphabets, numbers 0 to 9 and underscore.
`\-` matches a normal dash.

so `[\w\-]` would allow **numbers, alphabets, underscores and dashes** in the email alias.
(*it should be noted that `\.`, which allows a **dot**, is not included for the regex before `@` although, `.`s are allowed for email aliases*)